# how to redirect all requests from apache web server to load balancer to application url

Tags: apache-2.4, http, redirect

how to configure apache http server to redirect all incoming requests to load balancer by preserving web server url. How rewriteRule and rewriteCond have to be written

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you should not redirect requests from the Apache to the load balancer, but instead set the load balancer to accept the incoming reauests in place of apache and then send them to the serveral apache servers you want the load to be balanced between.

Set the load balancer to listen to the port 80 insted of apache or change the domain name to poin to the balancer system. Then enter backend servers to the balancer configuration.